# HTML Markup showing in "Reading" section, in traditional view

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I'm liking the new developer story so far, but...

## Traditional View

I'm seeing some markup in the final text here:
[image: Recommended Readings, in Traditional View]

## Story View

Looks just fine — except that it is clipped, without ellipsis `...` or any other indication. (Probably another bug.)

[image]

## Original Text

```
An intellectual perspective on Christianity, *Mere Christianity* makes well-reasoned arguments, which are difficult to disregard&nbsp;--- and a great read!
```

You'll note that I have a `&nbsp;` in the text, because I believe in typography! :-)

### Update

Changed `---` to an `&mdash;`, but that didn't help. Not that it would — `&mdash;` isn't magical or anything.

Comment: We're aware of this bug, I'll be soon fixed :)

Comment: @Stéphane Thanks! This is the kind of little thing which really makes a big difference.

Comment: Hey, I see the ellipses thing is fixed, too! Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (`2016.4.7.3442` on sites)

Comment: This is now fixed. Thanks!